# How to serialize and deserialize a CipherInputStream object

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I am having a problem serializing a cipherinputstream object. I always get this exception whenever i try to do this, here is a snippet of my code

```
public class Crypto implements java.io.Serializable
{

public Crypto(String filename)
{

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
SecretKeySpec secretkey = new SecretKeySpec(key(), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);
CipherInputStream cipt = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)), cipher)

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  ObjectOutputStream obj = null;

           try
           {
                obj =   new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                obj.writeObject(cipt);
                byte[] bv = baos.toByteArray();
                System.out.println(bv);

           }
           catch(Exception b)
           {
           b.printStackTrace();
           }
           finally
           {
            obj.close();
            baos.close();
           }
      }
     }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
```

Can anyone help me to do this. My aim is to convert the cipherinputstream object to bytes or bytearrays.

Comment: Did U implement serializable ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to write the cipher itself or really the object `CipherInputStream`?

Comment: the object CipherInputStream

Comment: @shuhail, how? Do not understand

Comment: The class of the object which U are trying to serialize...

Comment: @shuhail, i didnt do that. how i do it?

Comment: You can't serialize streams, any more than you can fax fax machines.

Answer (score -1):

Probably U wouldn't have implemented serialiazable marker class . Suppose class A is the one U need to serialize , then :

```
class A implements serializable {

  //class variables and methods


}
```